# Transaction failed but funds lost? (MEW)

Tags: ether

I sent some REQ to another of my addresses (via MEW) but it failed for some reason. The funds left my first wallet and did not reach my second, and they haven't been sent back. So now they're lost?

Can I retrieve them somehow? https://etherscan.io/tx/0x90d324abd889e4b40b137b88cf06154abc4b1f1148b4e843ee1a50326c6c4d08

Comment: The transaction failed, so it had no effect except that gas was paid for.

Comment: That's what I thought but for certain reasons I was sure I missed some REQ. But you were right. I miscalculated my balance hence the reason for my fears they were actually lost.